# DELETE using CURL with encoded URL

Tags: url, curl, encoding, request, http-delete

I’m trying to make a request using CURL like this:

```
curl -X DELETE "https://myhost/context/path/users/OXYugGKg207g5uN/07V"
```

where `OXYugGKg207g5uN/07V` is a hash, so I suppose that I need to encode before do this request.

I have tried `curl -X DELETE --data-urlenconded "https://myhost/context/path/users/OXYugGKg207g5uN/07V"`

Some ideas?

Comment: Is the server even receiving requests? It looks like you're URL encoding the whole URL... which would create an unusable URL.

Comment: Did you really try `--data-urlenconded`? Spelling this correctly might help you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If really `OXYugGKg207g5uN/07V` is the hash then you need to encode that, not the whole url. You can use an encoding function available inside the environment you use cURL in.

Comment: Im on bash script. Do you have some example?

Answer (score 22):

Since you are in a bash environment, you could encode the hash `OXYugGKg207g5uN/07V` before passing it to curl.

A straight-forward approach would be to use its byte representation `%4f%58%59%75%67%47%4b%67%32%30%37%67%35%75%4e%2f%30%37%56`

To get that, call:

```
echo -ne "OXYugGKg207g5uN/07V" | xxd -plain | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/\(..\)/%\1/g'
```

It will give you: `%4f%58%59%75%67%47%4b%67%32%30%37%67%35%75%4e%2f%30%37%56`

The complete one-liner including curl in bash/zsh/sh/… would look like this:

```sh
curl -X DELETE "https://myhost/context/path/users/$(echo -ne "OXYugGKg207g5uN/07V" | xxd -plain | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/\(..\)/%\1/g')"
```

and is equivalent to

```sh
curl -X DELETE "https://myhost/context/path/users/%4f%58%59%75%67%47%4b%67%32%30%37%67%35%75%4e%2f%30%37%56"
```

This solution is not very pretty, but it works.
I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Hm, not sure if I understand correctly, what kind of error do you get?
`sed 's/\(..\)/%\1/g')` is inside the `$()` evaluation, so escaping parenthesis is required. Without escaping them, sed will throw this error in sh, bash and zsh: `\1 not defined in the RE`.

Comment: comment deleted.  I was only using the part of the command I needed and missed part of the context.  disregard.